# Copy text to clipboard from background script in a Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am porting my Chrome extension over to Firefox. It has a paste to clipboard function. But, I have not yet had any luck with doing that in Firefox. Here is what I am trying to do in my background script:

```js
const input = document.createElement('textarea');
input.style.position = 'fixed';
input.style.opacity = 0;
input.value = text;
document.body.appendChild(input);
input.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
logger(text);
document.body.removeChild(input);
```

This works fine in Chrome. I have the `clipboardWrite` permission in my manifest. Any hints why it is not working with Firefox?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to do this from a background script, which won't work. The MDN page: "[Interact with the clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)" in "[Browser-specific considerations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Browser-specific_considerations)" says, for Firefox:

> You can write to the clipboard like this in all execution contexts *except background page*s. In Firefox you can't select text or focus an input field in background pages, so you can't write to the clipboard from a background page.

You will need to be in some other context to write to the clipboard. For instance, you could inject a content script, or open a tab or window to a page in your extension. How you choose to do so will depend on the additional permissions you already have for your extension (e.g. `tabs`), the tabs that are currently open (are there any tabs open in which you can inject a script) and what visual impact is acceptable to you (e.g. briefly opening a tab which you don't activate, which may, or may not, be perceptible to the user).

Comment: Great thanks for the hints and yeah it worked fine with content script. Thanks again